Why multiplication sign "*" turns into 0?
I was trying to make a calculator in bash and everything except multiplication works.
My script turns "*" into 0 when I try to multiply.
There is the code:
#!/bin/bash

calculator(){
  if [ $3 = "+" ] ; then
    echo [ $1 $3 $2 ]
  else 
    if [ $3 = "-" ] ; then
      echo [ $1 $3 $2 ]
    else 
      if [ $3 = "/" ] ; then
        echo [ $1 $3 $2 ]
      else
        if [ $3 = "*" ] ; then
          echo [ $1 $3 $2 ]
        else
          echo "$3 error"
        fi        
      fi
    fi
  fi
}

calculator 1 2 *


Probably something to do with * being expended by your shell. Try calculator 1 2 '*'. Also, checkout elif ;)

This is a pretty weird way of making a calculator. But to answer your specific question - put $3 in double quotes like so"$3" to prevent it being glob-expanded. And do what the previous comment said as well.

Yes, it expands to the files in your directory, you can check it like this ````#!/bin/bash
calculator(){
echo  "$@"

}


In addition to quoting * on the command line, you will need to (double-)quote the expansions of the corresponding parameter.  In fact, you should pretty much always quote expansions of any variables containing data provided by the user.

Also, although elif could help you simplify your function, I would probably use a case statement, myself, instead of an if / elif / else statement.

* is a wildcard, used for filename generation.

@Discussian fwiw ...  1 2 * is reverse polish notation (RPN); it was quite common (at least a few decades ago) to find RPN calculators (eg, HP) in use in engineering and scientific circles (certainly in use by a lot of STEM students at my college)

The dc utility already provides a desk calculator with reverse Polish notation. (Though you need 1 2 * p to actually print the result.)

Because when your shell sees calculator 1 2 *, it will first expand all glob patterns. The wildcard * means: 0 or more characters, any characters (with the exception of leading . denoting hidden files). Only after all expansions have run, your command will be invoked.
So if you have a file with the name 0 in your directory, * will first be replaced with 0, and then calculator 1 2 0 is invoked. If you have multiple files in your directory, such as 0, file.txt, image.png, then calculator 1 2 0 file.txt image.png will be invoked.
A similar problem applies to your line echo [ $1 $3 $2 ]. First, parameters are expanded and then path names are expanded for unquoted parameters. So even if you initially called calculator 1 2 '*', this line will first be expanded to echo [ 1 * 2 ], and subsequently expanded further to echo [ 1 0 2 ] (or echo [ 1 0 file.txt image.png 2 ], depending on the files in your working directory).
